# Need to create an XAML GUI to reference a local map (not on the MapServer site) that I'm using in ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, html

I know how to create an XAML GUI for a MapServer map . . .

```
<esri:Map x:Name="MyMap" Extent="-120,20,-100,40" >     <esri:Map.Layers>          <esri:ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer ID="StreetMapLayer"                Url="http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/ESRI_StreetMap_World_2D/MapServer" /> 
     </esri:Map.Layers></esri:Map>
```

However, I need to know how to set up the syntax for using a map that I created from a Shapefile Feature Class that I have brought into ArcMap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After referring to the following page . . .
Working with local data using SDK for WPF  http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/runtime-wpf/concepts/index.html#//01700000002q000000

I was able to come up with the following lines that I used in my MainWindow.xaml code . . .

```
      <!--Local Feature Layer-->
        <esri:ArcGISLocalFeatureLayer ID="arcGISLocalFeatureLayer" 
        Path= "C:\Temp\MapWithMyData_101212.mpk" LayerName="MyLayer"/>
```